# Common Lisp: Use undefined variable in function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to do something like that in Common Lisp:

```
(defparameter *fun* 
  (lambda () x))

(let ((x 0))
  (funcall *fun*)) ;should return 0
```

I want to access a local binding in a function, that is not defined, when I define the function.

If I use x as parameter, it would work, but I can't change the value of the variable:

```
(defparameter *fun* 
  (lambda (x) (setf x (+ x 1))))

(let ((x 0))
  (funcall *fun* x)) ;should return 1, would return 0
```

How can I do what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare the variable special (dynamic) at both the binding site and the reference site:

```
(defparameter *fun* 
  (lambda () (declare (special x)) x))

(let ((x 0))
  (declare (special x))
  (funcall *fun*))
```

Or globally:

```
(defvar *x*)  ;; makes *x* special

(defparameter *fun* 
  (lambda () *x*))

(let ((*x* 0))
  (funcall *fun*))
```

Late edit:

A macro might serve you better in this scenario. The only lexical bindings a function can access are the ones that were present when it was created. For example, the behavior you described is given by the standard in the macro incf. Define-modify-macro is a helper for defining macros similar to incf. http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defi_2.htm

Comment: I have to save my functions in lists, so it is not possible, to use macros, I think. I think declare and special is the best, but it seems not very beautiful. Maybe I simply use global parameters.

Comment: you only have to use declare special once outside the lambda-expression, so this is good

Answer (score 2):

You can define the function in the nested scope:

```
[2]> (defparameter *fun* (let ((x 0)) (lambda () (setf x (+ x 1)))))
*FUN*
[3]> (funcall *fun*)
1
[4]> (funcall *fun*)
2
```

If your function is defined outside the scope of a lexical variable, it can't access that variable, by definition of what is *lexical scope*. To be able to do that, it must be *inside* that scope.

The other way around this issue is to make the variable special, giving it dynamic extent:

```
[5]> (defparameter *x* 1)
*X*
[11]> (defun fun () (setf *x* (+ *x* 1)))
FUN
[12]> *x*
1
[13]> (fun)
2
[16]> *x*
2
```

Comment: You might modify the example a little bit, though.  The `defparameter` already has the effect of _globally_ declaring `*x*` special, so it's redundant within `fun`.   [m-n's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22815590/1281433) makes this a bit clearer by using `(declare (special x))` within the `let`, and within the `lambda`.